# How can I optimize a popup Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just starting with Javascript and I made this popup code, and I was wondering if there's another code with the same result or a way of optimizing the Javascript.

The code must make the popup appear when one of the options is clicked and disappear when the click is somewhere else.

[Popup code](https://codepen.io/AlexJMP/pen/YzVBdXJ)

```
var activePopup;
document.querySelectorAll('[hasPopup]').forEach((popupParent) => {
  popupParent.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (popupParent != activePopup && activePopup != null) {
      activePopup.querySelector('[popupContent]').style.display = 'none';
    }
    window.addEventListener('click', hasClicked => {
      let isOnPopup = false;
      hasClicked.path.forEach((event) => {
        if (event == popupParent) {
          isOnPopup = true;
        }
      })
      if (isOnPopup == false){
        popupParent.querySelector('[popupContent]').style.display = 'none';
      }
    })
    popupParent.querySelector('[popupContent]').style.display = 'block';
    activePopup = popupParent;
  })
});
```

Comment: If your code works your question might be seen as off-topic here and a better place could be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a JS popup than check this:- https://www.gitto.tech/posts/simple-popup-box-using-html-css-and-javascript/

It worked for me this way:

HTML code

```
     <div class="invalid-chars-alert-close-btn" onclick="document.getElementById('invalidChars-1').classList.toggle('active');">x</div>

JS: code inside if invalid characters written in my form then: 
      
    document.getElementById("invalidChars-1").classList.toggle("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do all that you require, but in a much shorter form

```js
puc=document.querySelectorAll("[popupContent]");  // popup divs ...
document.querySelector(".nav-bar__element").onclick=ev=>{
 // in case the user clicked on the inner span and not the div:
 const pel=[...ev.path].find(e=>e.hasAttribute&&e.hasAttribute("hasPopup"))
 if (pel) { 
  const el=pel.querySelector("[popupContent]");
  puc.forEach(d=>d.style.display=d===el?"block":"none")
 }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25fr 75fr;
}

.small-icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

[hasPopup] {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
}

[hasPopup]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[popupContent] {
    position: absolute;
  cursor: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
    left: 110%;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='nav-bar__element nav-bar__element--utils'>
    <div class='utils__notifications' id='utilsNotifications' hasPopup>
        <span>Notifications</span>
        <div class="notifications-popup" popupContent>
            <div>
                notifications
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='utils__messages' id='utilsMessages' hasPopup>
        <span>Messages</span>
        <div class="messages-popup" popupContent>
            <div>
                messages
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='utils__settings' id='utilsMessages' hasPopup>
        <span>Settings</span>
        <div class="settings-popup" popupContent>
            <div>
                settings
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</div>
```